# Can we create custom choice fields with scripts in Servicenow platform?

Tags: scripting, client-side, servicenow

I have t create a field in catalog task when the workflow matches some conditions on my instance but I was not able to do that. can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a field when the workflow condition matches?
Can your requirement be fulfilled by creating a UI policy instead which will make an already existing field available when the conditions are met?